# one class data classification tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am starting with tensorflow and deep learning and I want to classify some images to know if they belong to a class or not (for example dog or not dog).

Currently I have the class data wanted, but I am not sure how must be build the data set to the "not class". The data for that class could be any image not showing the wanted class (for example birds, buildings, bows, etc) or must fit some criteria? (for example only buildings), or maybe there is some way to train with only one class data?

Edit: More detail about I want to achieve, the idea behind detect only one class is because I want the system learn to classify a specific screen type, so later I could detect in a image where is the screen (using ssd or similar) to process that region later. In the use case, the image could show the screen or could show any other thing

Thanks!

Regards!!

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application. If your users are going to use your classifier to distinguish dogs and cats, your training examples for "not dogs" should be cats. If they are likely to input birds and buildings, you are going to need some examples of them in your training. Your training set should match, as much as possible, the distribution of your test setting.

Comment: I add more details in the question. The big problem is the user can use images where can be a screen (target object to classify) or could be any other thing (not bound to a specific object)